error: could not compile `spl-type-length-value` (lib) due to 10 previous errors
I'm having some problems when building. I hope you can help.
Thank you so much
Dependencies
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "sleep_to_earn"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
solana-program = "2.0.13"
spl-token-metadata-interface = "0.5.1"
spl-type-length-value = "0.6.0"



Instructions
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::rent::{
    DEFAULT_EXEMPTION_THRESHOLD, DEFAULT_LAMPORTS_PER_BYTE_YEAR,
};
use anchor_lang::system_program::{transfer, Transfer};
use anchor_spl::token_interface::{
    token_metadata_initialize, Mint, Token2022, TokenMetadataInitialize,
};
use spl_token_metadata_interface::state::TokenMetadata;

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(args:String)]
pub struct InitToken<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 6,
        mint::authority = payer,
        seeds = [b"token-2022", payer.key().as_ref(), args.name.as_bytes()],
        bump,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::authority = payer,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}

pub fn initialize_token(ctx: Context<InitToken>, args: TokenMetadataArgs) -> Result<()> {
    let TokenMetadataArgs { name, symbol, uri } = args;

    let token_metadata = TokenMetadata {
        name: name.clone(),
        symbol: symbol.clone(),
        uri: uri.clone(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let data_len = 4 + token_metadata.try_to_vec()?.len();

    let lamports =
        data_len as u64 * DEFAULT_LAMPORTS_PER_BYTE_YEAR * DEFAULT_EXEMPTION_THRESHOLD as u64;

    transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        lamports,
    )?;

    token_metadata_initialize(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            TokenMetadataInitialize {
                token_program_id: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                metadata: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        name,
        symbol,
        uri,
    )?;

    Ok(())
}



It looks like you're mixing solana-program v1 from the anchor dependency with solana-program v2 -- try to use all v1 crates if you're using anchor

thank you, solved  problem
